# Reactjs and Redux update state mutable or immutable?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm extremely new with Reactjs and Redux, anyone can explain what is Mutable and Immutable in reactjs/redux?

I'm using Redux to update state, and using it to control my UI layout, but I found one of the method below will not working, although both are also updating the object.

I've a store object such as below:

```
const initialAppState = {
          showSideBar: false,
          showSwitcher: false,
          showRightPane: false,
          menu: [
                {
                  name: "Home",
                  redirect: "/",
                },
                {
                  name: "About",
                  redirect: "/about",
                  expanded: false,
                  childs: [{
                      name: "Child one", 
                      redirect: "/Child"
                  }]
                },
            ]
        }
```

Beside that, I have a Pane.js and Menu.js to render my menu list.

**Pane.js**

```
const LeftPane = (props) => {
    return <List>
          {links.map((o, index) => {
            return <Menus key={o.name} props={o} index={index} />
          })}
    </List>
}
```

**Menu.js**

```
const Menus = ({ props, index, onToggleSubMenu }) => {
   return <ListItem> ...
}
```

I'm trying to update the expanded value to true for the menu object, but when I using state.menu.map to change the value, my react component won't re-render? It will execute to the Pane.js, and I can see the expanded = true from the Pane.js props. but it won't execute to the Menu.js?

```
const AppReducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {
    return {...state, 
          menu: [
            ...state.menu.map((m, i) => {
              if (i === action.index) {
                m.expanded = !state.menu[action.index].expanded;
                } 
                return m;
            })
          ]
        }
}
```

On the other hand, if I update the expanded value from the code below, it works.

```
const AppReducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {
   state.menu[action.index] = Object.assign({}, state.menu[action.index], {
      expanded: !state.menu[action.index].expanded,
    });
    return {...state, menu: state.menu}
}
```

What is the different between these two? What is the correct way to update state? Why we should use Object.assign or spread (...) operator to update state? I've read the [Redux Immutale Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), the working code above is more like the Common Mistake mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things which you should do differently in your `AppReducer`.

1. Map function returns a new array and does not mutate the original array, so no need to destruct there.
2. Inside your map function, you have the reference to the object m, and you are mutating the m by changing `m.expanded` to `!m.expanded`. This is where you should actually be returning a new object.

You should write `AppReducer` as following.

```js
const AppReducer = (state = initialAppState, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    // No need to destruct when using map, map always returns a new array
    menu: state.menu.map((m, i) => {
      if (i === action.index) {
        // Return a new object, with all properties copied, and expanded's value toggled
        return {
          ...m,
          expanded: !m.expanded;
        }
      }
      // Return the original object because no change has been made
      return m;
    }),
  };
};
```

As for the difference between the spread operator and `Object.assign`, according to [object-rest-spread-proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md), one is syntactic sugar of the other, i.e. `{...a}` is pretty much an easier way to write `Object.assign({}, a);`

Comment: Should be: `expanded: !m.expanded ` your code works but `state.menu[action.index]` is already available as `m`

Comment: My bad HMR, thanks for the update. I will update the answer.